# How do I update the data in jsGrid without the ability to use AJAX in the loadData() controller? (The array isn't finished populating yet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I can display static data `data: ary` and I'm successful with updating, deleting, inserting, and filtering said static data:

```
controller: {

    loadData: function (filter) {

        return $.grep(ary, function (obj, index) {
            return
            /* conditional logic for filtering here */
        });

    },

    updateItem: function (item) {

        //call custom framework function responsible for updating record
        appName.doRequest("updateRecord");

    },

    insertItem: function (item) {

        //call custom framework function responsible for inserting record
        appName.doRequest("insertRecord");

    },

    deleteItem: function (item) {

        //call custom framework function responsible for deleting record
        appName.doRequest("deleteRecord");

    },

},
```

Please note, `ary` is a global variable. Basically, I can update `ary` anytime I want through our custom framework; however, it must be outside of the jsGrid controllers, or the array ends up empty.

Why do I have to call the function responsible for populating the array whilst *outside* of `loadData()` in order for the array to become accessible?  How do I get my array to be available inside of `loadData()` when I call my company's special function?

The documentation says I can use AJAX requests with deferments/promises, but I don't believe our framework will allow for me to make direct AJAX requests to the backend.

Here's a snippet of the framework:

```
case "getJobSpecs":
    var jsonString, ary = [];
    var jsonString = $(data.xmldata).find("tblJobSpecs").text();
    ary = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    //results from server.  I can do anything to the DOM I want here
    break;

case "updateRecord":
    console.log(data.xmldata);
    //results from server.  I can do anything to the DOM I want here
    break;
case "insertRecord":
    console.log(data.xmldata);
    //results from server.  I can do anything to the DOM I want here
    break;
case "deleteRecord":
    console.log(data.xmldata);
    //results from server.  I can do anything to the DOM I want here
    break;
```

Comment: your snippet seems to indicate that `ary` is not in fact global and instead declared and set in the case `getJobSpecs`

Comment: @Steve it's declared as an empty array outside of the snippet shown here, and then defined in `getJobsSepcs`

Comment: `getJobSpecs` is limiting the scope of that `ary` variable.  Any changes made in `getJobSpecs` will not be visible outside that scope.  If you other manipulations of `ary` are in the same format that is your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Long story short, I was able to reload the grid with an updated array with this simple line:

```
$("#tblJobSpecs").jsGrid("option", "data", ary)
```

Observations:

1. `ary` is a **global var** updated through calls in our custom framework; even though I can call the framework from within the `loadData()` controller to populate `ary`, it's not available inside the `loadData()` function, for a reason I do not fully understand.
2. I no longer define the data option (now, the grid initializes with no data)

   ```
   $("#tblJobSpecs").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        //height: "400px",
        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        selecting: true,
        paging: true,
        filtering: true,

        //data:  ary

        ...
   });
   ```
3. After the DB has been modified through `updateItem()`, `insertItem`, or `delteItem()`, I redefine `ary` via our framework, then ...
4. ... I tell jsGrid to "refresh" the grid with:

   ```
   $("#tblJobSpecs").jsGrid("option", "data", ary)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **arr.filter** property and return the returns after checking your conditions,

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        height: "90%",
        width: "100%",
        filtering: true,
        editing: false,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageButtonCount: 5,
        deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",
        controller: {
            loadData: function (filter) {
                if (gridDataDb != undefined) {
                    for (var filterItem in filter) {
                        if (filter[filterItem] === "") {
                            $("#jsGrid").data("JSGrid").data = gridDataDb;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //this.data = Array.from($("#jsGrid").data("JSGrid").data);
                return $.grep($("#jsGrid").data("JSGrid").data, function (client) {
                    return (!filter.vcm_prescriberidname || client.vcm_prescriberidname.indexOf(filter.vcm_prescriberidname) > -1)
                        && (!filter.npid || client.npid.indexOf(filter.npid) > -1)
                        && (!filter.vcm_territoryname || client.vcm_territoryname.indexOf(filter.vcm_territoryname) > -1)
                        && (!filter.vcm_countryidname || client.vcm_countryidname.indexOf(filter.vcm_countryidname) > -1)
                        && (!filter.vcm_statefullname || client.vcm_statefullname.indexOf(filter.vcm_statefullname) > -1)
                        && (!filter.vcm_city || client.vcm_city.indexOf(filter.vcm_city) > -1)
                        && (!filter.vcm_zip || client.vcm_zip.indexOf(filter.vcm_zip) > -1)
                        && (!filter.currmonthsum || client.currmonthsum.indexOf(filter.currmonthsum) > -1)
                        && (!filter.lastquartersum || client.lastquartersum.indexOf(filter.lastquartersum) > -1)
                        && (!filter.thisyearsum || client.thisyearsum.indexOf(filter.thisyearsum) > -1)
                });
            }
        },

        fields: [
            { name: "vcm_prescriberidname", title: "Prescriber Name", type: "text", width: 20 },
            { name: "npid", title: "NPI ID", type: "text", width: 20 },
            { name: "vcm_territoryname", title: "Territory Name", type: "text", width: 20 },
            { name: "vcm_countryidname", title: "Country", type: "text", width: 20 },
            { name: "vcm_statefullname", title: "State", type: "text", width: 20 },
            { name: "vcm_city", title: "City", type: "text", width: 20 },
            { name: "vcm_zip", title: "ZipCode", type: "text", width: 15 },
            { name: "currmonthsum", title: "Curr Month TRx Sum", type: "text", width: 10 },
            { name: "lastquartersum", title: "Last Quarter TRx Sum", type: "text", width: 10 },
            { name: "thisyearsum", title: "Last Year TRx Sum", type: "text", width: 10 },
            //{ name: "vcm_prescriberidname", title: "Location", type: "text", width: 7 },
            { type: "control" }

        ]
    });
```

Look at the above piece of code,
Two key notes:

1. Load Data through $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("option", "data", your_Data_Array).
2. Filter out data without Ajax using Array.filter.

NOTE: The filter object reference contains an Object containing all the columns in the jsGrid, So when filters are applied, the respective column with that filter value updated in the respective column is passed to the data set to filter the results.

Let me know if that helps !